Efficiency of fixed conjoint analysis (CBC)
I want to do a choice based conjoint analysis to understand what features matter the most. I need to pass the questionnaires in person, on paper, due to legal reasons beyond my control. I only have 6 plausible alternatives with 5 different attributes with 3, 2, 2, 2, 3 levels, respectively. Unfortunately, attribute 1 is pretty much perfectly correlated to attributes 4 and 5.
Given the logistical aspect of running the experiment, I have thought of creating a "fixed" CBC questionnaire, meaning that each of the 200 individuals approximately that I will be able to recruit, will face the very same 10 tasks where they have to 2 alternatives to choose from. Therefore my design, by construction, is the same 10 tasks repeated 200 times, exactly the same. How efficient is this design when running a conditional logistic regression to obtain the paremeters estimates? How would you compute this efficiency, given that a D-optimal design might not be possible given the low set of alternatives?
PS. Due to collinearity I'll probably drop two of the three correlated variables.
